# OutOfMemoryError Java Error when using a custom view in Android and the device goes into sleep mode

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-custom-view

I'm getting the standard java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in Android when using a custom view I created in a layout. I am using a bitmap but what I don't understand is this only occurs when the device goes into sleep mode. I debugged the code and found for some reason when the device goes into sleep mode it runs the constructor on the custom view again which I've no idea why it would, the code for custom view is below, can anybody explain why the constructor is being run again when the device sleeps? And also, if there are some obvious errors in my handling of the Bitmaps would be nice as I know I'm going wrong somewhere. Thanks a lot...

```
public class LogoView extends View {

private static final int[] FRAMES_FILE_NAMES = { R.drawable.logo0000,
        R.drawable.logo0001, R.drawable.logo0002, R.drawable.logo0003,
        R.drawable.logo0004, R.drawable.logo0005, R.drawable.logo0006,
        R.drawable.logo0007, R.drawable.logo0008, R.drawable.logo0009,
        R.drawable.logo0010, R.drawable.logo0011 };

private Bitmap[] mBitmapFrames;

private Context mContext;

private int mHeight;
private int mWidth;
private int mLeftPadding;

private float mScale;

private boolean mResourcesLoaded = false;

public LogoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;
    mBitmapFrames = new Bitmap[FRAMES_FILE_NAMES.length];


}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (!mResourcesLoaded || mBitmapFrames[0].isRecycled()) {

        mHeight = this.getHeight();
        Bitmap preProc = ((BitmapDrawable) mContext.getResources().getDrawable(FRAMES_FILE_NAMES[0])).getBitmap();
        int preProcHeight = preProc.getHeight();
        int preProcWidth = preProc.getWidth();
        mWidth = (int) (((double) preProcWidth / (double) preProcHeight) * (double) mHeight);
        mScale = (float) mHeight / (float) preProcHeight;
        mLeftPadding = (int)(((double)(((WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()-(double)mWidth))/2d);

        Matrix matrix;
        for (int x = 0;x<FRAMES_FILE_NAMES.length;x++) {

            preProc = ((BitmapDrawable)mContext.getResources().getDrawable(FRAMES_FILE_NAMES[x])).getBitmap();
            matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.reset();
            matrix.postScale((float)mScale,(float)mScale);
            mBitmapFrames[x] = Bitmap.createBitmap(preProc, 0, 0, preProc.getWidth(), preProc.getHeight(), matrix, false);          
        }
        preProc.recycle();
        mResourcesLoaded = true;


    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapFrames[0], mLeftPadding, 0, null);

}
```

}

Comment: OK, no idea why this is but essentially what happens is when put into sleep mode, the view gets detached from the window and then the Activity starts again?!? So it's like the activity is restarting when the device goes to sleep... I don't understand why this is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running activity in landscape mode? I guess you setup in manifest `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` no? What I found out is that in that case when activity is going to stand by she is recreated once more as portrait..

To prevent it, notify Android that you will handle screen orientation by adding following line in Activity section in manifest file:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

hope that will solve your problem.

Cheers ;)